# How to convert html post_content to block editor in WordPress ? ( While import CSV )

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

How to convert html post_content to block editor  in WordPress ? ( While import CSV )

I wanted to convert all html tags with block editor codes in wordpress. But It cannot without JS. Is it possible in PHP?

**Is it possible to convert to block editor codes while import CSV file ?**

```
<h2>The apple tree (Malus pumila, commonly and erroneously called Malus domestica) is a deciduous tree in the rose family best known for its sweet, pomaceous fruit, the apple. </h2>

<p>It is cultivated worldwide as a fruit tree, and is the most widely grown species in the genus Malus. The tree originated in Central Asia, where its wild ancestor, Malus sieversii, is still found today. Apples have been grown for thousands of years in Asia and Europe, and were brought to North America by European colonists. Apples have religious and mythological significance in many cultures, including Norse, Greek and European Christian traditions.</p>

<img src="http://localhost/demo/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/16764902337724-16764902303769-swan-7606921__340.jpg" alt="apple" width="300px">

<p>Apple trees are large if grown from seed. Generally apple varieties are propagated by grafting onto rootstocks, which control the size of the resulting tree. There are more than 7,500 known cultivars of apples, resulting in a range of desired characteristics. Different cultivars are bred for various tastes and uses, including cooking, eating raw and cider production. Trees and fruit are prone to a number of fungal, bacterial and pest problems, which can be controlled by a number of organic and non-organic means. In 2010, the fruit's genome was sequenced as part of research on disease control and selective breeding in apple production.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a test environment, import the content then try the [Convert To Blocks plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/convert-to-blocks/) to see if that works for your content. It really depends on what the content is to what result you will get. If its all simple content like your example, it may possibly work well for you.